# Форма создания объявления в Django

Tags: javascript, django, form

У меня есть форма для создания объявления в Django, внутри которой можно добавить несколько изображений. При загрузке изображений они отображаются в предпросмотре и имеют "крестик" для того чтобы отменить их загрузку.
Проблема в том что при загрузке изображений и нажатии на крестик изображение удаляется из предпросмотра. но при сохранении формы все равно остается в форме. Как сделать возможность отмены загрузки определенных изображений?

views.py:

```
@login_required
def additem(request):
    image_form = ItemImageForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        files = request.FILES.getlist('image')

        form = ItemForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            if not files:
                form.add_error(None, "Необходимо загрузить хотя бы одно изображение.")
            else:
                item = form.save(commit=False)
                item.author = request.user
                item.save()

                for file in files:
                    ItemImage.objects.create(item=item, image=file)
                return redirect('main:index')
    else:
        form = ItemForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'image_form': image_form,
        'categories': Category.objects.all()
    }
    return render(
        request,
        template_name='main/additem.html',
        context=context
    )
```

additem.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'main:additem' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
          {% csrf_token %}
            <!-- Изображение -->
            <div class="file-dnd">
                <label class="upload-image">Фотографии
                    <br><span style="color: #958f8f; font-weight:600;">Не более 10</span>
                </label>
                {{ image_form.image }}
                {% if form.errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 1em;">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        {% if form.non_field_errors %}
                            {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                                {{ error }}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                        {% for field in form %}
                            {% for error in field.errors %}
                                {% if field.name == 'image' and field.errors %}
                                    Необходимо загрузить изображение.
                                {% endif %}
                                {% if error != 'Обязательное поле.' %}
                                    {{ error }}
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
                <div class="after-upload">
                    <div class="before-upload">
                        <div>
                            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">add_circle</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="image-preview-container">
                        {% for image in item_images %}
                          <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt="Previous Image">
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

          <div class="btn-save-wrapper">
            <button type="submit" class="btn-save">Сохранить</button>
          </div>
</form>
```

upload-image.js:

```
function applyDnDFile(el) {
    const beforeUploadEl = el.querySelector(".before-upload");
    const inputFile = el.querySelector("input[type='file']");
    const imagePreviewContainer = el.querySelector(".image-preview-container");
    let totalImages = 0;

    function showImagePreviews(files) {
        if (totalImages + files.length > 10) {
            alert("Вы не можете загрузить более 10 изображений.");
            return;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            const imgContainer = document.createElement("div");
            imgContainer.classList.add("image-container");

            const img = document.createElement("img");
            const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
            img.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);

            const deleteIcon = document.createElement("div");
            deleteIcon.classList.add("delete-icon");
            deleteIcon.innerHTML = "&times;";

            imgContainer.appendChild(img);
            imgContainer.appendChild(deleteIcon);
            imagePreviewContainer.appendChild(imgContainer);

            totalImages++;
        }
    }

    function removeImagePreview(container) {
        container.parentNode.removeChild(container);
        totalImages--;
    }

    beforeUploadEl.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        inputFile.click();
    });

    inputFile.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (e.target.files.length > 10) {
            alert("Вы не можете загрузить более 10 изображений.");
            inputFile.value = "";
        } else {
            showImagePreviews(e.target.files);
        }
    });

    imagePreviewContainer.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        if (e.target.classList.contains("delete-icon")) {
            const container = e.target.parentNode;
            removeImagePreview(container);
        }
    });

    // Обработчик событий для удаления изображений
    imagePreviewContainer.querySelectorAll('.delete-icon').forEach(icon => {
        icon.addEventListener('click', function() {
            const container = this.parentNode;
            removeImagePreview(container);
        });
    });
}

applyDnDFile(document.querySelector(".file-dnd"));
```